# csync/sqlite error when running ownCloud command

Tags: sqlite, owncloud

I am running owncloudcmd to sync files from a local* path to an ownCloud/Nextcloud server, all running Debian 8. However it fails with the error:

> [5] csync_statedb_query  sqlite3_compile error: disk I/O error - on
>   query PRAGMA quick_check; [6] csync_statedb_load  ERR: sqlite3
>   integrity check failed - bail out: disk I/O error.  #### ERROR during 
>   csync_update :  "CSync failed to load the journal file. The journal
>   file is corrupted."

I am not very familiar with csync or sqlite so I am a bit in the dark and although I can find talk of this issue through googling, I can't find a fix. The data in this case can be dumped to start over so I'm happy to flush any database or anything else. I've trying removing the created csync and journal files assuming one of them was corrupted but it doesn't seem to change anything.

I have read talk about changing PRAGMA settings to ignore the error (or check) but I can't see how this is implemented either.

Is anyone able to show me how to clear out the corruption?

*the local file is a mounted path to an AWS S3 bucket but I think this is irrelevant because it is working on other systems fine.

Comment: Which version of `owncloudcmd` are you using? If you update to latest 2.3.3rc2 version of the ownCloud client, there's some extra logs (https://github.com/owncloud/client/pull/5725) that might help us find the problem. Find it here: https://owncloud.org/changelog/desktop/. 

Also, make sure you have the right permissions to write on the local path you're trying to sync. And on a side, important note, make sure files starting by `._` are not vetoed in your local path (which happens in some SMB setups)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have installed 2.3.3-rc2 and do see more information scroll down the screen. Is that what you mean or are you referring to new log files themselves? Some points I am seeing is `Sqlite prepare statement error: "disk I/O error" in "PRAGMA quick_check;"
Error running quick_check on database
Consistency check failed, removing broken db "/media/nextcloud/._sync_ec6a54b695b5.db"`

Comment: AND `[5] csync_statedb_query  sqlite3_compile error: disk I/O error - on query PRAGMA quick_check;
[6] csync_statedb_load  ERR: sqlite3 integrity check failed - bail out: disk I/O error.
 #### ERROR during  csync_update :  "CSync failed to load the journal file. The journal file is corrupted."
void OCC::SyncJournalDb::close() "/media/nextcloud/._sync_ec6a54b695b5.db"` I have found that if I sync another path (not remote mounted S3 path) it works OK. However I don't think it's a perms issue because I do see the journal files being written to the path. I am syncing OK with S3 on another VM.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. Could you elaborate on the vetoing of `._` files? How many of these files should there be? I'm not sure what veto here means really but if I see one on S3 I believed it was working in that part as expected.

Comment: The client included in 2.3.3 a patch to fallback when the local folder's underlying filesystem does not support file names starting with `._` (https://github.com/owncloud/client/pull/5844) - this was a problem on [SMB  mounted drives](https://www.e-rave.nl/disable-creation-of-ds_store-files-on-samba-shares). Maybe something similar happens on S3-mounted drives; will try to reproduce. Could you try to `touch ._example` on your local folder?

Comment: how are you mounting your S3 bucket?

Comment: I am mounting with s3fs. This package comes default with Debian 9 and can be installed via a PPA in 8. I am having the same problem with both setups. However, it is working on a third system that is running in a VM which is also Debian 9.